# git user info questions

Tags: git, github, commit

Not sure if this would be better on Programmers or another Exchange but here goes:

I'm planing on using git and github for my first project and had some committer user info questions.

When I set up my global username, should I use my full name or my username for github or even one then the other with a dash between or something? I don't really know exactly what it is they see based on what I choose. I'm not worried about people knowing who I am, just wondering how it works.

Should I set an email for it? How accessible is that email address to web crawlers and such or should I even worry about that? It's a gmail address so I was thinking of using the + command to let gmail automatically turn it into its own label (that's how it works right?). I would probably do portaljacker+github@gmail.com or portaljacker+git@gmail.com since it's a bit shorter.

I'm very new to git and VCS' in general so I'll be having a lot of questions like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name and email you use in your Git global configuration is not used by Github for authentication. Github uses SSH keys for authentication, so you can put anything you like in the name/email.

You can later associate your Github account with one or more emails that you use in Git commits.

Github doesn't seem to actually show email addresses in the web interface (at least, I can't find them at the moment and I don't recall whether they used to show them or not). Assume, however, that the email address used is completely accessible to any crawler. Gmail has spam filters, so don't worry about it.

Comment: The email address is only shown, if it is contained in the commit message, like the Signed-off-by line. But i contributed to some projects with that Signed-off-by-line and couldn't notice more spam on that address.